# Python 2.6 virtualenv, pip throwing "ImportError: No module named _md5"

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I've been developing a django site (irrelevant) under python 2.5 up until now, when I wanted to switch to python 2.6 to make sure things worked there.  However, when I was setting up my virtualenv for 2.6, pip threw an error "ImportError: No module named _md5".

Background:

- I'm running on Ubuntu Maverick 10.10.
- My python 2.5 was coming from [fkrull's deadsnakes repo](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12720), and has been working without issues.
- I create virtualenvs with `virtualenv <path> --no-site-packages --python=python2.[56]`

If I try to import hashlib from outside a virtualenv, it works fine:

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>>
```

But inside it throws the same ImportError.

I've tried reinstalling python2.6, libpython2.6, and python2.6-minimal and recreating my virtualenv, but I get the same error.

None of the [list of potential duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+%22no+module+named+_md5%22) didn't help, as they either use different linux distros or simply say "recompile python".

Ideas?

Comment: I got tricked by module name. what is _md5 anyway? I am not aware of any module named _md5 in default python install

Comment: From what I understand, _md5 is a wrapper around a C library, or maybe a C module.  `import _md5` at the python shell fails with an ImportError, too, so I wonder if hashlib is doing some magic in there somewhere.

Comment: yes it's a C module used internally by hashlib (probably named with an _ to ease the process of md5 module deprecation); your problem has to do with your upgrade and virtualenv running a different python/dep version; I suppose your fix (wiping out and recreating the venv from scratch) is the only fix :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem ended up being different versions of python2.6 -- my virtualenv (which I had actually created at an earlier date to the same purpose) already had python 2.6.4 installed, while the system was up to 2.6.6.

I had tried `virtualenv <path> --no-site-packages --python=python2.6 --clear`, but apparently `--clear` doesn't clear out the old python bin.

`rm -rf`-ing the env directory and recreating it from scratch (so the venv had 2.6.6 as well) fixed the issue.

Comment: I have same error, but while creating the virtualenv ... any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I used virtualenv checked out from external repository. Inside virtualenv I had 32-bit python2.6.4 and inside my local system I had 64-bit python 2.6.6. When I typed

```
>>> import hashlib
```

inside my virtualenv I received the same exception (`ImportError: No module named _md5`). The real problem was with importing `_hashlib` module. It threw an exception `ImportError: libssl.so.0.9.8: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. The solution was to install `ia32-libs` package.